# Run subset of commands in parallel; once one command is done, run another

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency

Let's say I have `N` bash commands stored in a file:

```bash
$ cat list_of_commands.txt
do_thing_1
do_thing_2
...
do_thing_N
```

The goal is to run them in parallel, but only `10` at a time (to avoid overloading the CPU).  So, the first batch of commands (`do_thing_1` to `do_thing_10`) starts running in parallel, and as soon as one of them are done, `do_thing_11` should start running.  When another command is done, `do_thing_12` starts.  Etc.  Until all `N` commands are done.

I've found the GNU `parallel` tool but after tinkering with it, I'm unsure if it's the right tool for the job.

Thanks in advance! 
~ Rijk

Comment: GNU parallel tool is the right tool

Comment: `xargs` can also do this, and will typically be available by default when `parallel` is not. (See the `-P` option to `xargs`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest use:

```
cat list_of_commands.txt | parallel -j10
```

Read more:

- Cheat sheet https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf
- Book https://zenodo.org/record/1146014

Comment: Oh wow, it was that easy all along.  Thank you for the reply and for your work on `parallel`!